# Leader Follower Ros package

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ros

I'm trying to run this package https://github.com/danfergo/DucklingsFollowLeader 
there are soo many errors : ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ducklings_follower/walker]: can't locate node [walker] in package [ducklings_follower] (same thing for listener )
Error reading element ; 
Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file;
no namespae found ; and others 
Can someone pleaaase help

Answer (score 0):

U need To source `setup.bash` in your catkin workspace(`<path-to-your-catkin-worksapce>/devel/setup.bash`) in order for the ROS System To find The Package U compiled.
all Of The Errors You Are Getting is Because of That.

Comment: Did the package compiled with no error and could you see it upon catkin_make ( or catkin build )? And check the folders for .cmake and compiled binaries in `devel/share/<package-name>` ( for cmake) `devel/lib/<package-name>` ( for binaries)